# Mysqli SELECT * not working

Tags: php, mysqli

Code looks fine, but it is not retrieving the "GroupMembers". Help?

```
<?php
        $ID = $db->real_escape_string(strip_tags(stripslashes($_GET["ID"])));
        $GetGroupByID = mysqli_fetch_object(mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM Groups WHERE ID='$ID'"));

        $GetMembersTrunc = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM GroupMembers WHERE GroupID=$GetGroupByID->ID ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0, 12") or die(mysqli_error());
?>

<?php while ($gMT = mysqli_fetch_object($GetMembersTrunc)): ?>
        ljlsdlfks
<?php endwhile; ?>

// shows no errors with "or die(mysqli_error());" and the text "ljlsdlfks" isn't appearing

// looks 100% fine to me
```

Comment: Does $GetGroupByID actually return the object with ID in it?

Answer (score 2):

change this: GroupID=$GetGroupByID->ID
to this: GroupID='{$GetGroupByID->ID}'

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this and see if it works:

$GetGroupByID = mysqli_fetch_object(mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM Groups WHERE ID=$ID"));

Answer (score 0):

Is your $ID a numeric parameter ? If yes then try this code

```
$GetGroupByID = mysqli_fetch_object(mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM Groups WHERE ID=$ID"));
```